# YII2 on blur Ajax validation not working

Tags: php, ajax, validation, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I was trying to validate my YII2 change password form. But I'm stuck on YII2 on blur validation.

```
    <?php

        use yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm;
        use yii\helpers\Html;
    ?>
    <?php
        $form = ActiveForm::begin([
                    'id' => 'change-password',
                    'action' => $action,
                    'enableAjaxValidation' => true
        ]);
    ?>
<?php echo $form->field($model, 'old_password')->label(false)->passwordInput(['placeholder' => 'Your Old Password', 'class' => 'form-control']); ?>


<?php echo $form->field($model, 'new_password')->label(false)->passwordInput(['placeholder' => 'Your New Password', 'class' => 'form-control']); ?>


<?php echo $form->field($model, 'confirm_password')->label(false)->passwordInput(['placeholder' => 'Confirm Your New Password', 'class' => 'form-control']); ?>


<?php echo Html::submitButton('Submit', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary')); ?>
    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Can anyone let me know what wrong I am doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not enough to just include it in `ActiveForm` config.

The requests can be sended but the form will stay unchanged.

You should also prepare your controllers (in CRUD generated controllers they are `create` and `update`, in your case it can be just one - which is responsible for updating password) to return proper JSON data in case of AJAX request.

See how it's done in [official documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html#ajax-validation).

Comment: i am sending proper json error after validating in controller. but page is getting redirected to target action..

Comment: It's not clear from your question. Add controller code and more details. And also what value $action variable have? From information you provided this is the most probable reason of the error.

Comment: json output will be useful for analysis too.

Answer (score 0):

Model class Scenario function must have a default option:

```
public function scenarios()
{
    return [
        'default' => ['old_password', 'new_password', 'confirm_password']
    ];
}
```